# jquery uncheck parent if current element is check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html markup

```
<ul>
    <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="1">Smith</label></li>
    <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox"  value="2">Emma</label></li>
    <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox"  value="3">Peter</label></li>
    <li>
        <span><input class="user" name="profiles[]"  type="checkbox" value="admin"></span><a href="#">Admins<i class="fa fa- caret-down"></i></a>           
        <ul class="" style="display:  block;"> 
            <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="michael">Michael</label></li>
            <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="ashley">Ashley</label></li>
            <li>
        <span><input class="user" name="profiles[]"  type="checkbox" value="robert"></span><a href="#">Robert<i class="fa fa- caret-down"></i></a>

               <ul class="" style="display:  block;"> 
      <li><label><input class="user"  name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="steve">Steve</label></li>
      <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="jennifer">Jennifer</label></li>
       <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="rock">Rock</label>
           </ul>

        </li>

       <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="jack">Jack</label></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ckoe9q3L/5/

when user checks admin, and then checks Michael, I want it to uncheck admin.

I am not able to uncheck admin, if user checks Michael

and another example user checks Robert and then checks Steve. So it should uncheck Admin and Robert but keep Steve checked

```
$('.user').change(function() {

    var c = this.checked;

    if (c) {
        $(this).parent().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing in your javascript (});).

Comment: @Jonast92 Not in the fiddle

Comment: @AshleyMedway Fair nuff.

Comment: Quick comment as to why it's not working - `parent()` goes up the chain one step, then `find(':checkbox')` goes right back to where you were.  That's why you can't check anything as it stands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like

```js
//target only checkboxes in the second level
$('li ul input.user').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('ul').siblings('span').find('input').prop('checked', false)
});
//if want to uncheck Michael when Admins is clicked
$('li:has(ul) > span input.user').change(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings('ul').find('input').prop('checked', false)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />Smith</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="2" />Emma</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="3" />Peter</label>
  </li>

  <li><span><input class="user" name="profiles[]"  type="checkbox" value="admin"/></span><a href="#">Admins<i class="fa fa- caret-down"></i></a> 
    <ul class="" style="display:  block;">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="michael" />Michael</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="ashley" />Ashley</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="robert" />Robert</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="jack" />Jack</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: he might wanna uncheck Micheal too when he clicks admin

Comment: this works, but I need to uncheck all the parents. sorry for not posting it in the question. lets say there is another ul under Robert. so if user clicks a child of Robert it should uncheck admin and robert but keep the child clicked

Comment: @meWantToLearn what is here are 2 lists like the `Admins`(ie with child items) and you selected 1 item from one child and then tries to select another child from second list

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks, I have updated the fiddle, it can be more than 2 lists http://jsfiddle.net/ckoe9q3L/5/

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks alot. but its unchecking Michael. Michael is not in the ul of Robert. it shouldnt be affecting michael

Comment: @meWantToLearn ,check the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ckoe9q3L/7/

In one line

```
  $(this).parents().siblings('span').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT 3**

```js
$('.admins').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).parents().siblings('ul').find('input:checkbox').prop( "checked", !this.checked );
    }
});

$('.user').change(function() {
    $(this).parents().siblings('span').find('input:checked').prop( "checked", !this.checked );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="1">Smith</label></li>
 <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox"  value="2">Emma</label></li>
 <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox"  value="3">Peter</label></li>
 <li>
  <span>
   <input class="admins" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="admin">
   <a href="#">Admins<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
  </span>
  <ul style="display: block;"> 
   <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="michael">Michael</label></li>
   <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="ashley">Ashley</label></li>
   <li>
    <span>
     <input class="admins" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="robert">
     <a href="#">Robert<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    </span>
    <ul style="display: block;"> 
     <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="steve">Steve</label></li>
     <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="jennifer">Jennifer</label></li>
     <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="rocky">Rock</label></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><label><input class="user" name="profiles[]" type="checkbox" value="jack">Jack</label></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I found. Its just one line and simple